# Exporting region of interest (ROI) from scatter plot in ENVI

Tags: envi

I have a scatter plot of LST (y-axis) amd NDVI (x-axis) on ENVI 5.3. I selected some points from the distribution as a region of interest. When I export the ROI, I found only the value of Y. However, I need to get both the value of X and Y for deriving a linear equation. So, can any one assist me the steps to do.